# Notification to know nstableview column start resizing

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a MAC application in which I need to get an event that user start resizing column of nstableview. I know there is a notification columnDidResize. But it get called when we ended resizing columns.

Answer (score 4):

Solved the same problem using KVO notifications.

Set your table delegate as an observer for NSTableColumn width:

```
[column addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"width" options:0 context:nil];
```

Options argument could be adjusted to get the notification before an actual change takes place.

Then get notified when the width changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSInteger resizedColumn = tableView.headerView.resizedColumn;
    if (resizedColumn != -1)
    {
        if (object == column && 
            object == [tableView.tableColumns objectAtIndex:resizedColumn])
        {
            // User is resizing column
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! Don't forget to remove the observer if you ever remove that column

Answer (score 0):

Using KVO, as indicated by @pointum works. If you get into troubles related to unregistering the observer, you can do what I actually ended up doing:
Subclass NSTableColumn and override the setter for the Width parameter and send a notification from there.